# How do AngularJs download file from ASP.MVC5 passing parameters

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, ajax, download, blob

I have an ASP MVC5 API that generates an excel.xlsx and returns it in a FileContentResult. All in memory, as I can not save the file to the server disk. It works ok if I access the url directly.

I have an AngularJS application that needs to pass a huge Json to the API and receive the generated .xlsx file.

I'm trying the following:

Controller:

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> Excel([FromBody]GetGeneralFilterVM operationHistoryFilter = null)
{
    var ListaOperazioni = await GetListaOperazioniData(operationHistoryFilter);
    var Totals = await GetExcelTotalsData(operationHistoryFilter);

    var excelExport = new ExcelExportEntity(new object[]
        {
            ListaOperazioni,
            Totals,
        });
    var preFile = excelExport.DoExcel();
    var arraybits = preFile;
    var file = File(arraybits, "application/vnd.ms-excel", "OperationHistory.xlsx");

    return file;
}
```

Angular:

```
$scope.exportExcel = () => {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: appPath + "controller/Excel",
    data: filter, 
    success: function (response) {
        var file = new Blob([response], { type: "application/vnd.ms-excel" });
            var fileName = "excelFeliz.xlsx";
            saveAs(file, fileName);
        },
        error: function (ajaxContext) {
            alert('Export error: ' + ajaxContext.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

This will even download a file, but when trying to open it is corrupted.

My insistence on AJAX is because of the GetGeneralFilterVM that I am getting in the controller, it contains sub objects with many properties would be very complicated to put this as parameters in the url.

I also have no way to generate and return a url to download, because I can not save the file to the server disk.

Any idea?

Comment: can you try to change the mime type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" instead of " "application/vnd.ms-excel" ?

Comment: That is!!! First I change in server side. It's not work. Then I change only in Ajax call, but the file remains corrupted. Finally, I have also change the extention from .xlsx to .xls and this work fine! Thak's for this tip.

Comment: Before more tests I realized that the data in excel file as dirt and when it was going to open excel claimed that the extension was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mime type to "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" instead of " "application/vnd.ms-excel"

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I found a way, this one works 100%. Instead of using AJAX, which seems to have problems with blob, I used an XMLHttpRequest call. Note: The controller has not been changed.

```
getExportExcel: function (filter) {

    var json_upload = "operationHistoryFilter=" + JSON.stringify(filter);
    var url = appPath + "OperationHistoryReport/ExcelGeneral";
    var fileName = "excel.xlsx"
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.responseType = 'blob';

    request.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var blob = this.response;
            if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
            }
            else {
                var downloadLink = window.document.createElement('a');
                var contentTypeHeader = request.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob], { type: contentTypeHeader }));
                downloadLink.download = fileName;
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
            }
        }
    };
    request.send(JSON.stringify(filter));
}
```